# How do I change the location of iCloud drive on Windows?

Tags: icloud, windows

Recently I've been using iCloud with my windows machine. With the older version of iCloud I was able to change the location using the mklink command; however, this does not seem to work with the new iCloud version downloaded from the windows store, as I cannot move the iCloud folder even when all iCloud processes are closed (it says I don't have enough space on drive C even though that's not the drive I'm moving to). Is there another method for moving the iCloud folder that I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If it's saying you don't have enough space on your C drive then that drive isn't big enough to hold all your iCloud content.  How much space are you using in iCloud and how much free space do you have on your C drive?

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, its telling me that the C drive doesn't have enough space despite the file already being on the C drive while I'm attempting to move it to my second drive. I'm using ~200 Gb on my iCloud and have ~40 gb available on the C drive, however optimize storage it turned on so that the actual iCloud folder is only taking a few hundred megabytes.